# Maven release process phases

Tags: maven

I am a liitle confused about the release process in maven. As I googled it, I found it to be a two step process:

1. Prepare
2. Perform
3. ***Preparing*** a release goes through the following release phases:

a)Check that there are no uncommitted changes in the sources

b)Check that there are no SNAPSHOT dependencies

c)Change the version in the POMs from x-SNAPSHOT to a new version (you will be prompted for the versions to use)

d)Transform the SCM information in the POM to include the final destination of the tag

e)Run the project tests against the modified POMs to confirm everything is in working order

f) ***Commit the modified POMs***

g)Tag the code in the SCM with a version name (this will be prompted for)(name for the release)

h)Bump the version in the POMs to a new value y-SNAPSHOT (these values will also be prompted for)

i) ***Commit the modified POMs***

2. ***Performing*** a release runs the following release phases:

a) Checkout from an SCM URL with optional tag

b) Run the predefined Maven goals to release the project (by default, deploy site-deploy)

what confuses me is why do we commit the POM in ***preparation*** phase when we are checking out the same POM(that we commited in preparation phase) in ***perform*** phase?

When we already had the POM, why do we commit and then check it out again?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this resolved? If so please consider [upvoting/accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When step i) is done you again have a `xxx-SNAPSHOT` version number in the POM. That's the new version you'll be developing against. Hence, you can't make a release based on that POM. The release needs to be created against the tag you created in step g).

Furthermore, Maven ensures that you don't tinker with the artifacts (thereby creating uncommitted changes) during the release process. That's why it checks out the entire source tree during the perform phase rather than relying on the artifacts you already have locally on your file system.